# RTL8822be driver for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless

The RTL8822be chipset does not have a compatible driver when using kernel 5.0 and above. As a result, either your wifi adapter will be undetected or you will be unable to see any visible networks when scanning. I've tried many suggestions online but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You originally posted this solution in your question:

> Finally, I came across a solution which works.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install git dkms
> git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
> cd rtl8812au
> sudo make dkms_install
> ```

Comment: Thank you Pilot6. I really dont know what happen with this computer. When I buy this notebook (Lenovo ThinkPad E490) Windows 10 was installed. I used for months with no problem, but I preffer free softwares. I replaced by Ubuntu 18.04. At firsts days the wifi worked during few minutes and turn off. I tryed several solutions. Now is worst, the wifi adapter isn't apper at list (lshw -c network) and the Ubuntu start at "fly mode"

Comment: @DouglasVitoreti you may like to ask your own question to try to get help with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have Lenevo Legion y530 with realtek 8822be wifi driver. I had spent days of figuring out how to install realtek driver and finally made it work on Ubuntu 18.04. Here are the steps along when you are in a given situation.

**Fresh installation of Ubuntu where you can see the Wifi option in the top right corner but don't see any network**

1. Go to https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 and follow all the steps. Restart the PC and you should get the wifi working.
   If this doesn't work then do the following:
2. Check the modules loaded using `lsmod|grep rtw`. If there are modules starting with prefix other than "rtw_" then blacklist them. Reinstall the drivers from step1.
3. Check the dmesg using `dmesg|grep rtw` and look for error messages. If it is :`Refused to change power state, currently in D3` then create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/50-rtw_pci.conf` and write the following in it: `options rtw_pci disable_aspm=y disable_msi=y`.

**Don't see the wifi adapter itself in top right corner**

1. Run `echo "options r8822be aspm=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf`, install the drivers again and reboot.

**ACPI BIOS error during boot which indicates wifi driver can't be read**

1. Install 5.1 kernel and boot into it. Then quit and start your normal kernel version(may be 5.4 or so).