# Lenovo's Wifi RTL8822BE not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm new to linux I'm using linux on my laptop but the only problem is that the wifi not working before the laptop was on windows and the wifi working

I think this information can help to find a solution

```
admin@Lenovo:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-54-generic
admin@Lenovo:~$ uname -s
Linux
admin@Lenovo:~$ uname -n
Lenovo
admin@Lenovo:~$ uname -v
#60~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 17:25:16 UTC 2020
admin@Lenovo:~$ uname -m
x86_64

admin@Lenovo:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff

admin@Lenovo:~$ lspci
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter

admin@Lenovo:~$ lspci -k
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device b023
    Kernel modules: rtwpci, wl

admin@Lenovo:~$ inxi -nx
  Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
             IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A

admin@Lenovo:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

if I do `sudo modprobe rtwpci` return nothing.

If i do
`lsmod | grep rtw`

return

```
rtwpci                 24576  0
rtw88                 610304  1 rtwpci
mac80211              851968  2 rtwpci,rtw88 
cfg80211              712704  2 mac80211,rtw8
```

And If I do
`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

I get

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961 [144d:a804]
```

Comment: Try this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263141/rtl8822be-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04

Comment: @BernardDecock I tried the solution but at the last line `sudo ./dkms-install.sh` I get `sudo: ./dkms-install.sh: command not found`

Comment: You need to fix the PATH.      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo

Comment: Please remove the incorrect driver: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot and show us: `dmesg | grep rtw` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 `dmesg | grep rtw` return nothing

Comment: What happens if you `sudo modprobe rtwpci`

Comment: The info above says that the driver *rtwpci* is loaded. Check: `lsmod | grep rtw` Also, may we see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: I update my question to add the result of the commands