# Lenovo Legion Y530 wifi-card not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, realtek

as the title says my problem is that the wifi card is not detected and I do not know how to solve this. Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: rtw_8822be
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the wifi card worked fine, but suddenly it did not detect any network and then I tired to restart the network manager `sudo service network-manager restart` and then the adapter was not detected.

**Edit2:** After disabling the secure boot and following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263141/rtl8822be-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04) the outpout of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` remains the same:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: rtw_8822be
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RTL8822be driver for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263141/rtl8822be-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04)

Comment: Unfortunately no, DKMS tree already contains: 8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025

Comment: Is Secure Boot enabled?  `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes, it is

Comment: disable it as the kernel won't allow unsigned modules to load with it enabled

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did disable secure boot and then rebooted the device following this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS) but nothing changed, I don't know if I should do anything further.

Comment: Edit the post to include new results for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did, but it seems to remain the same output.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425180/300665 and post a link to wireless script result

Comment: Here it is [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wdxTNCfWDp/), I wish I will be able to understand it too one day. @Jeremy31

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe rtw88` and post a URL for `dmesg | egrep -i 'rtl|rtw'| nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: Hello @Jeremy31, I noticed after running the script you previously mentioned, the wifi card is detected but no there are no visible networks, anyway here is the [url](https://termbin.com/8gbi)

Comment: Try `echo "options rtw88_pci disable_aspm=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtw.conf` then reboot

Comment: Nothing happened, I mean, wifi adapter is still not recognized. @Jeremy31

Comment: Try updating the BIOS, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872984 comment 17

Comment: My knowledge is limited in doing that... I noticed that the output of lspci -v is the [following](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/K6PtZZFwj3/), could that be the issue ?