# RTL8822BE drivers not working Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 21.04, realtek-wireless

I am still very new to Ubuntu, and have had this issue ever since I made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu on my laptop. The WiFi card is the Realtek RTL8822BE and I have tried installing drivers multiple times with seemingly no success in sight. I feel like I have exhausted all possible solutions to no avail.

I have previously posted a question on this topic (now deleted) because I was unable to get an Internet connection to my laptop, but now that I figured out a way to get an Internet connection, does anyone know how I could fix this issue? Thanks

EDIT: I have tried installing the rtw88 and rtl8821ce drivers which did not change anything (not sure if it was the way I did it or if the drivers just don't work), I tried restarting network-manager but when i run the command to restart it, it says it doesn't exist but when I go to install it, it says it's already there and up to date. At the moment, when I turn WiFi on, it shows the Visible Networks tab, but it's empty. The moment I turn WiFi off, it says "No WiFi adapter found". Also, none of these drivers appear in the list of "Additional Drivers" in settings.

EDIT (again): I don't know if it's important to note, but my Bluetooth works just fine, it's the WiFi that does not want to work at all.

Comment: @stebs You could try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1263246/928088 Though it suggests installing RTL8812AU (instead of RTL8822BE), it's an accepted answer.

Comment: @Jags oh yes i forgot to mention i have also tried to install this driver. i followed the same thread a few days ago and still no success.

Comment: I was just looking around in settings to see if I could find anything and I noticed there was a setting to toggle proprietary drivers for devices. Should I disable it?