# Wifi suddenly stops working after opening Youtube

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I've a Lenovo flex 6-14, dualboot Windows and Ubuntu 23.04.
After a month of no problems, suddenly wifi problems started.
**The wifi stops working after i open e.g a youtube video**. Then the wifi button dissapears. The way i fix it is to restart.

To make sure it's not a hardware issue, i used Windows for a week, without any wifi problems.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595 [17aa:b023]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822be
```

I installed rtl8812au-dkms as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263141/rtl8822be-driver-for-ubuntu-18-04-and-20-04), but rtw_8822be is still in use. Not sure if i should mess with this in the first place.

Any ideas?

Comment: That was a different issue, rtl8812au-dkms  will not work with 8822be, run this in terminal and reboot `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.